# Writing an Axis2 handler

Tags: apache-axis, handler, rampart

I am trying to write 2 Axis2 handlers but there is there is something missing I can't put my hand on

The first handler is supposed to start at the very beginning before anything else, it will read the message header, parse the information I want from it and save it to a file then move on.

The second handler will execute after Axis2's Rampart finishes operation, which I assume is after the security phase. It will read the file and execute the logic on it (it wont touch the message contex)

I tried reading the guide on Axis2's website but it was not very beginner friendly, if someone can guide me to a simple way to approach this I would be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the handlers in order. That is, you have to add the execution phases(In/out/fault flows) and define your handlers in order there. For example, check the axis2.xml, and how they defined the phases/handlers there.

Check this [guide](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/writing-simple-axis2-handler.html)